# Mysql how to exclude a subset from a set?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, set

I have a dummy table as below shown which showing who own the food. `null` mean the food is common owned. I am thinking a query to get what food that owner own. Let's say owner A, the output will be the below output. If the owner also own the stuff which is commonly owned, the output will only print '2' instead of '1' & '2'. I have tried the query with `not exist` but still can't get through the logic. How can I achieve the logic I want? Thanks!

```
Table t:
ID   OWNER   FOOD
1    null    rice
2    A       rice
3    B       apple
4    null    orange

Output:
ID   OWNER   FOOD
2    A       rice
4    null    orange

Tried query:
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.OWNER= 'A'
AND NOT EXISTS (    ....
                )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using this exists logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    OWNER = 'A' OR
    (OWNER IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                                   WHERE t2.FOOD = t1.FOOD AND t2.OWNER = 'A'));
```

### Demo

The logic here is to retain any record where the owner be `A`, *or* any record with a null owner, provided that we have not already included an `A` record with the same food as that null record.

**Edit:**

If you need the above query to run faster, you may optimize it by adding the following composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (OWNER, FOOD);
```

This should speed up the `WHERE` clause in the outer query, as well as speeding up the exists lookup.

Comment: May I ask why you use "select 1" instead of "select *"?

Comment: No reason, and either would work.  On some databases, there _might_ be an advantage to using `SELECT 1` over `SELECT *`.

Comment: Any faster way to achieve this logic? I found that not exist takes long time to finish it when the data is bulk

Comment: @WILLIAM Add an index, q.v. my updated answer above.